# jQuery checked attribute not seen when using html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a specific problem where I need to render a html string from the server and show it to the user. The user then clicks the checkboxes and I transform it back into a html string and save it on the server.

Problem is after the user clicks the checkboxes, the transformed HTML string does not contain the checked attribute.

Here is a snippet

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){

   console.log($("#container").html());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
    <button> Test </button>
</div>
```

But when I manually click the checkbox and click the button and examine the console log, **the checked attribute inside the HTML string is not seen**.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check a checkbox manually, the `checked` HTML attribute doesn't change.

You can change it yourself by selecting every checked checkbox and manually updating them with the jQuery [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector:

```
$('#container input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('checked','true');
```

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $('#container input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('checked','true');
  console.log($("#container").html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  <button> Test </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `checked` attribute manually by `.attr('checked', 'checked')` on change:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {

  console.log($("#container").html());

});

$('#checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
  } else {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
  <button> Test </button>
</div>
```